# Just the slidename of the last value of an array gets selected in Powerpoint when a presentation is opened from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to open a master Powerpoint presentation with 400+ slides from Excel and then select just a few of them based on some names in an array.

So the aim of this code is to open up a Powerpointfile called "testpp.pptm" and then select only the slides which are called "Master" and "USA".

Right now it opens up the Powerpoint but only selects the last value in the array. So only the "USA" slide is selected when I run the macro and not the "Master" slide.

```
Sub openandselectslides()

Dim testarray As Variant

testarray = Array("Master", "USA") ' <<< These are the slide names I want to be selected

Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
ppt.Visible = True


ppt.Presentations.Open "\\Desktop\Current File\testpp.pptm" '< file path

Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set ppres = ppt.ActivePresentation

ppres.Application.Activate ' << I tried to see if activating the presentation worked

Dim selectedSlideRange As SlideRange

Set selectedSlideRange = ppres.Slides.Range(testarray)


selectedSlideRange.Select


End Sub
```

The slide names can also be "Slide 1", "Slide 2" ofc

Thanks for all of the help. This is how the slides get named.

```
Dim slidename As String
slidename = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name

Dim Newname As String
retry:
Newname = InputBox("give new name")
If Trim(Newname) = "" Then Exit Sub

Dim s As Slide

' check if this slide name already exists
On Error GoTo SlideNotFound
Set s = ActivePresentation.slides(Newname)
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Slide name already exists"
GoTo retry

Exit Sub

SlideNotFound:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name = Newname
MsgBox "Slide name has changed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing to slide sorter view before selecting.

Comment: What do you need to do with the selected slides, or more specifically, why do you need to select slides at all?  Generally it's bad practice to select anything unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: So the reason is that I want to automate the process of creating Powerpoint presentations. I have a table in Excel which gives me new data everyday and I also have a master powerpoint file with 400+ slides where I manually create custom presentations everyday based on the regions that the table shows that day. I want to automate this process so instead of having to go through 400 slides if I one day have data from "India", "Sweden" and "USA" then I'd like automatically create a Powerpoint presentation with only the "India", "Sweden" and "USA" slide.

Comment: As Steve has noted, it's better to work with the Range object rather the Selection object. Slides don't actually have names. You may be referring to the text in the Title placeholder, which is often used as a name substitute. If that's what you're referring to, you'll have to iterate through every slide to find the title text and build an array of slide indexes for slides that have the right title. Then use that array to copy and paste slides to a new deck.

Comment: So you should be able to copy the selected slides with `selectedSlideRange.Copy` and paste them in a new presentation with `newPPres.slides.Paste`, where `newPPres` is a variable that represents another presentation.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I added how I "name" the slides in the post, and thanks for pointing that out John. I now understand why the slides did not get selected. The newPPres.slides.Paste works great, thanks so much. However the format and template that I'm using does not get copied over to the new presentation. Is there an easy way of solving this?